# Java Running Sequentially but concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

This may seem silly but is it possibly to run sequentially but also concurrently using Threads? For example see the below code:

```
public void processMessage(Socket socket) {
     char[] data = buildData(socket.getInputStream());
     int primaryKey = saveRecord(data);
     // do something else
}

public char[] buildData(InputStream inputStream) {
    return new char[5];
}

public int saveRecord(char[] data) {
   // save to database and return primary key
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        processMessage(socket.getInputStream());
   }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();

Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       processMessage(socket.getInputStream());
   }
};
new Thread(runnable2).start();
```

What I am trying to do is start one thread and the full set of methods are executed and then the other Thread starts and fully completes. This is because I receive some data, read the data, insert into the database and I have other things but would like to avoid database update concurrency issues.

Actually, this is a TCP application where the data comes from the socket and the data does not arrive immediately. Before I had a single threaded application, but because the application was too slow to run and the data from the socket was not arriving in one ago I introduced Threads. Now the full set of data comes on the TCP Socket, but I would like to avoid database concurrency issues.

The above is only example code.

I understand the basics of Threads and I know each Thread has its own stack, but I want to keep the database insert/updates correctly so to avoid any data conflicts.

EDIT:

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;

public void acceptData() {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket("somePort");
      socket = serverSocket.accept();
      Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              processMessage(socket.getInputStream());
          }
      };
      new Thread(runnable).start(); 
}
```

This is what I am doing. On each loop I create a new thread, so that the socket is not blocked and keeps on sending data while the threads are managed concurrently.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about your requirement? Do you want the to wait for the first Thread to be guaranteed to have finished its work before the second thread runs? And if so, what is the difference between that and sequential code?

Comment: Yes, I want to the first thread to complete first. The problem is that on the socket layer that data does not arrive in one ago. When I started to introduce Threads the full set of data on the TCP socket layer was being received.

Comment: 'Sequentially but concurrently' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a classic producer/consumer pattern, right?

It looks feasible just synchronizing both threads with a single semaphore.

```
private Object semaphore = new Object();

public void processMessage(Socket socket) {
    synchronize(semaphore) {
        char[] data = buildData(socket.getInputStream());
        int primaryKey = saveRecord(data);
        // do something else
    }
}

public char[] buildData(InputStream inputStream) {
    return new char[5];
}

public int saveRecord(char[] data) {
    // save to database and return primary key
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        processMessage(socket.getInputStream());
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();

Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        processMessage(socket.getInputStream());
    }
};
new Thread(runnable2).start();
```

With this implementation the first thread receiving a message will start the processMessage execution and we will stop the execution for the other thread until it completes.

Is this what you was looking for?

Comment: I didn't understand. Could you show some example code to explain please?

Comment: I understand the basics of Threads and I know each Thread has its own stack, but I want to keep the database insert/updates correctly so to avoid any data conflicts.

Comment: Do you mean that the first thread that receives the message will start the processMessage execution and once completed all the steps will possibly move onto the other thread to start?

Comment: Yes, what really happens is that the first thread receiving the message will "close the door" to execute the code inside the "synchronized" block. When it completes the execution... it will "open the door" again and next waiting will execute the code. Any code trying to execute synchronized block, will wait until the "door is open".

Comment: It doesn't look this this solution works. Will I need to put a sycnhronized on each of the method that the processMessage() calls? It looks like differnt threads are being run.

Comment: If you are calling every any of the methods out of processMessage call, yes you have to add the synchronized to all of them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. processMessage() contains two methods and processMessage() has a synchronized block that contain the two method calls. Will I also need to put a synchronized block within the other two methods calls with the semaphore?

Comment: The problem is that I am creating one thread per loop and I want to avoid insert/update problems so no data conflicts. Will your solution work?

Comment: Please see edit above. I have tried to explain the problem. Basically when data arrives the processMessage() is processed concurrently.

Comment: I suggest you to read about synchronized threads. I think that the proposed code should cover your current requirement. When you synchronize a block of code by an object means that this block on code will not be executed concurrently by any other thread. So, if the Only way to execute both methods is via processMessage, you don't need to add more synchro. But, if there is any other call to any of that methods (saveRecord for instance) out of processMessage, you will need to add more synchro blocks... But... It depends about how the rest of the code interacts with these three methods.